# Unit Test for "Unknown class *** in Interface Builder file" bug

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder, xib

Does anyone have an idea how to write a unit test that will detect this kind of errors?

Error ("Unknown class *** in Interface Builder file") appears in the console, but view loads successfully and test passes.

```
func testViewLoadedSuccessfully() {

    vc.loadView()
    let view = vc.view

    XCTAssertNotNil(view, "View should not be nil.")
}
```

**Update**

This simple test shows that vc is loaded (init it from xib).

Error occurs when I set a `Class` in Interface Builder from wrong `Module`. In my project I have many `Module`s (`Target`s)

If I set wrong `Module` project compiles but app crashes when view controller tries to load view.

My case is it to write test which will find this case without run app.

[image]

Comment: Did you add the file to the unit test target?

Comment: Where is "vc" declared? Does the error message literally show "***" as the class name?

Comment: I should think trying to cast your vc as? MyVCClass would end up nil if it isn't the right subclass.